# unable to print the dynamic value in place of title

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on angularjs application.I'm getting the response back from angularjs controller and printing the values in the html page.
I can able to iterate and show the results in the html page but **unable to print the dynamic value in place of title**. I tried the follwing two ways to print the value but unable to get the value.

```
 1)  Results for ID -  {{myResultsData.myID}}  

 2) Results for ID - <label ng-model="myResultsData.myID"/>
```

Below is the code.

js code:

```
app.controller('myResultsController', function ($rootScope,$scope,$uibModalInstance,$location,MyService,id) {
     MyService.getResultsData(id).then(
        function(response) {
            $scope.myResultsData = response;
        },
        function(errResponse){
            console.error('Error!!!');
        });
});
```

results.html

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title"> Results for ID - {{myResultsData.myID}}</h3> <!--unable to print the value for myID-->
</div>
  <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="data in myResultsData">
            <td align="center">{{data.name}}</td>
            <td align="center">{{data.percentageSpread}}</td>
            <td align="center">{{data.status}}</td>
        <td align="center">{{data.comments}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: $scope.myResultsData = response.data is correct suntax;

Comment: @Ved - But when i tried that, unable to see the results in <table> .Before with my above code i can able to display results in table, only issue was unable to print the title. Now with  
$scope.myResultsData = response.data  i cannot see any dynamic data printed on the page.

Comment: is this  MyService.getResultsData apicall?

Comment: Yes MyService.getResultsData is an API call. I can able to get the response without any errors in angular controller, no issue with that. And as i said i can able to see the results when iterated inside the table <tr ng-repeat="data in myResultsData">. Only issue is unable to print the title with code {{myResultsData.myID}}. And as suggested i tried with  
$scope.myResultsData = response.data  but no results are displayed on the page.

Comment: id i injected is dynamic based on the user request. and i have that id value in myResultsData response also.@HadiJeddizahed

Comment: check my updates.  I think, myResultsData[0].id will work

Comment: @Ved - It worked,thanks :)

Comment: there are **6,350!!** results for [angular $http response](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=angular+%24http+response).  I found at least 3 on the first page alone that refer to the correct syntax for `$http`, not to mention the official documentation.  This doesn't seem like a clearly researched question....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function(response) {
            $scope.myResultsData = response;
        },
```

should be

```
function(response) {
            $scope.myResultsData = response.data;
        },
```

Edit 1:
myResultsData is Array, hence this should work

```
Results for ID - {{myResultsData[0].myID}}
```